# Function C++>Tcl with Critcl

Tags: c++, tcl

I would like to extend Tcl with mathematical functions, I have a simple C++ function like that :

```
double dotproduct(double vect1[3],double vect2[3])
{double res;
res=vect1[0]*vect2[0]+vect1[1]*vect2[1]+vect1[2]*vect2[2];
return res;
}
```

I searched on the Wiki and I saw that **Critcl** can do, and I tried :

```
critcl::config language c++
critcl::clibraries -lstdc++

critcl::ccode {
#include <math.h>
} 
critcl::cproc dotproduct {double vect1[3] double vect2[3]} double {
    return vect1[0]*vect2[0]+vect1[1]*vect2[1]+vect1[2]*vect2[2];
  }
```

But I have this error:

> FAILED   critcl.tcl: In function 'int tcl__dotproduct16(ClientData,
>   Tcl_Interp*, int, Tcl_Obj* const*)': FAILED   critcl.tcl:4831:44:
>   error: cannot convert 'double' to 'double*' for argument '1' to
>   'double c__dotproduct16(double*, double*)'

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critcl code isn't very sophisticated when it comes to type mapping; it's just lowering the arrays to pointers to arrays and that's just not very nice for you, especially as it doesn't enforce the number of elements in the arguments. In this case, you're best doing it yourself.

Note that we need to also pass in the `interp` special and return the `ok` special “type” (so we can do error reporting), and we use the `Tcl_Obj*` type for the arguments, which disables (virtually) all the type mapping.

```
critcl::cproc dotproduct {Tcl_Interp* interp Tcl_Obj* vect1 Tcl_Obj* vect2} ok {
    int listc;
    Tcl_Obj **listv;
    double v1[3], v2[3];

    if (Tcl_ListObjGetElements(interp, vect1, &listc, &listv) != TCL_OK)
        return TCL_ERROR;
    if (listc != 3)
        // You probably should also do an error message here
        return TCL_ERROR;
    while (listc-->0)
        if (Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj(interp, listv[listc], &v1[listc]) != TCL_OK)
            return TCL_ERROR;

    if (Tcl_ListObjGetElements(interp, vect2, &listc, &listv) != TCL_OK)
        return TCL_ERROR;
    if (listc != 3)
        return TCL_ERROR;
    while (listc-->0)
        if (Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj(interp, listv[listc], &v2[listc]) != TCL_OK)
            return TCL_ERROR;

    double res = v1[0]*v2[0] + v1[1]*v2[1] + v1[2]*v2[2];

    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewDoubleObj(res));
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

We need to do a little more work on the out-side of things too, as we've had to disable the automatic mapping there in order to be able to generate errors.

Comment: It would be fair to say that critcl is designed more for interfacing with C code than C++; it's not as sophisticated as, say, SWIG. On the other hand, that also makes it much more predictable for non-expert use…

Comment: Thanks @DonalFellows for the explanations , I still have errors 'error: cannot convert 'Tcl_Obj**' to 'Tcl_Obj***' in argument passing
 if (Tcl_ListObjGetElements(interp, vect1, &listc, &listv) != TCL_OK)' I am going to try to look SWiG

Comment: @Mkn Sorry; was missing a `*` from the definition of `listv` there. Typo…

Comment: not that it changes much, but one could use the `list` parameter type for `vect1` and `vect2`.

Comment: @mrcalvin The best alternative, if you're doing this sort of thing a lot, is to define a new critcl type mapping for lists-with-three-doubles. Not worthwhile for a one-off function, but would make doing a whole suite of these things much easier.